# Black background for three.js sprites with depthTest true

Tags: three.js, transparency

[image]

I have been experimenting with converting the custom attribute BufferGeometry example (https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_custom_attributes_particles.html) into a fly through animation and I find that the sprites have dark backgrounds (and those that I create myself as well) if depthTest is set to true. See the image.

The sprite in the custom attribute example has a transparent background but this appears to be ignored when it is rendered if depthTest is set to true.

I have tried numerous custom blending rules but cannot find a way to remove the background, only to reduce the effect a bit. The background disappears if depthTest is set to false.

Is this a known limitation? Is there a work around?

I am modifying this question to add clearer images with a different ball sprite (also with a transparent background). This image has depthTest set to true for the custom ShaderMaterial used in the https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_buffergeometry_custom_attributes_particles.html three.js example.

[image]

By comparison, this uses multiple PointsMaterials from a different three.js example (https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_points_sprites.html), also with depthTest set to true and using the PointsMaterial map parameter for the sprite.

[image]

As you can see, the second PointsMaterial example works as expected. Because PointsMaterial only accepts one fixed size and color, I need to create 36 different point geometries to render this image.

I would prefer to use the custom shader in the first example (which has custom size and color attributes and requires only one geometry). Is there a way to define a custom shader to support depthTest like the PointsMaterial does?

Answer (score 6):

WebGL has a depth buffer that's used to find out which pixels are hiding behind other pixels. If a pixel is hiding behind another, it doesn't get rendered. Typically that's what you would want, why would you waste GPU time rendering pixels you're never going to see? Consider the example depthbuffer below, white squares are closer to the camera, while darker squares are further away:

[image]

If there was a square hiding behind another one, you wouldn't see it in the depthBuffer, you'd only see the closest one. The depthBuffer doesn't know that your squares have partial transparency and you want some parts to be see-through. This is an issue in other realtime engines too, this is an example from Unity:

[image]

The squares that are closer are blocking part of the squares that are further away in the depthBuffer, so the occluded pixels don't get rendered. That's why setting [depthTest to false](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.depthTest) is useful. You're basically telling the renderer to stop testing which pixels are behind others, and just render all of them. Here it is again with `depthTest = false`:

[image]

If you **must** set depthTest on, (for instance, if you want the sprites to hide behind a solid wall) you could [set `depthWrite` to false](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.depthWrite) on the sprite material. It would still check which pixels are behind others, but the pixels from the sprites wouldn't get written to the depthBuffer, so no sprite could block another sprite.

```
depthTest: true;   // Tests pixel depth
depthTest: false;  // Does not test pixel depth
depthWrite: true;  // Writes pixel depth to depthBuffer
depthWrite: false; // Does not write pixel depth to depthBuffer
```

As far as blending mode, I prefer `THREE.AdditiveBlending` because it gives the particles a nice glowing effect when they accumulate one on top of the other. But that's up to you.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I think that my original question was not clear enough. I have added more examples.  Three,js does seem to support depthTest with the PointsMaterial example, but not the custom shader example. I am trying to understand if there is a way to adjust the custom shader so that it works as the PointsMaterial does.

Comment: Also, turning depthWrite off does not work in my case. It is essential that the balls display in the correct order. When I turn depthWrite off, the display is not correct.

Comment: I thought you were open to trying different blending rules. That's why I recommended `THREE.AdditiveBlending` since additive colors don't have ordering issues when they overlap.

Comment: AdditiveBlending does not allow the opaque balls that I want to achieve - but I'm sure it would be useful for other use cases where translucent objects are desired.